# How to validate class parameters in __init__?

Tags: python

I've been searching a lot for this type of problem, haven't found a single similar question on SO yet.

I have tried using a for loop to put some validation in the train's init that would disregard those passengers although with no success.

tl;dr - How do I validate which passengers will be in the passengers list when I know that some of the passengers in the passengers list are ineligble to be in the train, due to seat_nr out of range or the carriage_nr out of range.

```
"""Train."""


class Train:
    def __init__(self, passengers: list, carriages: int, seats_in_carriage: int):
        

        #--Insert validation for passengers allowed on train--#        

        self._passengers = passengers
        self._carriages = carriages
        self._seats_in_carriage = seats_in_carriage

    @property
    def passengers(self) -> list:
        return self._passengers

    @property
    def carriages(self) -> int:
        return self._carriages

    @property
    def seats_in_carriage(self) -> int:
        return self._seats_in_carriage

    def get_seats_in_train(self) -> int:
        return self._seats_in_carriage * self._carriages

    def get_number_of_passengers(self) -> int:
        return len(self._passengers)

    def get_passengers_in_carriages(self) -> dict:
        return {}

    @passengers.setter
    def passengers(self, value_list: list):
        self._passengers = value_list

    @carriages.setter
    def carriages(self, value: int):
        self._carriages = value

    @seats_in_carriage.setter
    def seats_in_carriage(self, value: int):
        self._seats_in_carriage = value


class Passenger:
    def __init__(self, passenger_id: str, seat: str):
        self.carriage_number = seat.split("-")[0]
        self.seat_number = seat.split("-")[1]
        self._seat = seat
        self._passenger_id = passenger_id

    def __dict__(self):
        if str(2) >= self.seat_number > str(0) and self.carriage_number <= str(3):
            passenger_dct = {'id': str(self._passenger_id), 'seat': str(self._seat)}
            return passenger_dct


if __name__ == '__main__':
    passengers = [
        Passenger('test', '1-2'),   #--"test"= passenger_id, "x-y" : x= carriage_nr, y= seat_nr// valid
        Passenger('test2', '2-3'),  #-- invalid, seat_nr=3, train carriage has only 2 seats.
        Passenger('test3', '4-2'),  #-- invalid, carriage_nr = 4, train only has 3 carriages.
        Passenger('test4', '3-2'),  #-- valid
        Passenger('test5', '1-1'),  #-- valid
        Passenger('test6', '1-0'),  #-- invalid, no seat_nr 0 on train carriage
    ]
    assert passengers[0].__dict__() == {'id': 'test', 'seat': '1-2'}

    t = Train(passengers, 3, 2)  #--passengers list, number of carriages, number of seats in carriage.
    
    print(t.get_number_of_passengers()) # -- Should print 3, instead prints all 6.
```

Any info regarding to the topic is much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: I would turn this question around with a different question: does a passenger without a train make sense? If not, then `Passenger` could be a nested class of `Train`, and a [factory method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) could be added to `Train` that adds, validates, and returns `Passenger` instances. i.e. `train.add_passenger(passenger_id="passenger-id", seat_nr=1, carriage_nr=2)`.

Comment: Thank you for this comment, very interesting approach!

Comment: @AttilaViniczai your overall point is a good one, but why a nested class? It solves no problems.

Comment: @Crimson what do you mean by "I have tried using a for loop to put some validation in the train's init that would disregard those passengers although with no success." **exactly**?

Comment: As an aside, your getters and setters are completely pointless and should just be regular attributes

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I have tried comparing some of these class parameters with one another, something like this:        `  for passenger in passengers:
            if passenger.carriage_number <= self._carriages and passenger.seat_number <= self._seats_in_carriage:
                #valid passengers, keep them in the list. (append to a new empty list?) `

Comment: Sorry, couldn't get code tags to work for some reason ...

Comment: @Crimson **don't post code in the comments**. Edit your question to include a [mcve]. Please remove all the unecessary details that just obscure what's going on. And try to give a precise problem statement. In any case, when you tried that code **what didn't work**. Please be **precise**. Check out [ask] and the [help]

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga my suggestion of nesting `Passenger` within `Train` is based on [domain-driven design](https://hu.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design). My thought process is the following: if passenger only makes sense in the train context, then this constraint should be reflected through nesting. However this is only an opinion, `Passenger` can also exist outside of `Train`.

Comment: @AttilaViniczai that is simply not a pythonic construct. The fundamental unit of code organization in Python is a *module*. The more conventional approach would be to have an appropriately named module, then make `class Train: ...` and name `class _Passenger: ...` which lets everyone know that `_Passenger` is an implementation detail of the model, and not a public part of the module's API

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes, I agree that nesting classes is not Pythonic in the sense that it is generally avoided by Python devs. Also, +1 for pointing out that a module should be used for organizing said code, and indicating module internal constructs with an underscore prefixed name.

Comment: I think carriage should be its own class and the train accept a collection of passengers and carriages

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution is pretty straightforward and I'm not sure why this wouldn't work: *"I have tried using a for loop to put some validation in the train's init that would disregard those passengers although with no success."* Essentially you can just loop through the passenger list and filter out invalid passenger objects as such:

```py
self._passengers = list(filter(lambda p: p.seat_number is valid, passengers))
```

This uses a lambda function to check certain criteria for including them in the final list. Also your getters and setters don't currently do anything so they are kind of pointless.

Comment: Do note that above solution tightly couples `Train` and `Passenger` classes on the implementation level. In other words changes made to one, can affect the other.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I tried to do it this way, however since there is nothing that indicates whether a seat_number is valid I tried comparing passenger class seat_number and carriage_number to the train class number of carriages and number of seats. However I mostly got attribute errors :/.

Comment: That should not be so difficult to achieve, attribute errors probably mean you have not added those attributes to the class before calling them but I won't know without more info. @AttilaViniczai You are right and I look forward to your answer